# Joining Two Tables with Big Query Connected to Google Sheets

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables on which the first 3 columns are the same. I need to copy all the columns from Table 2 that are not found in Table 1 and paste them after all the columns in Table 1 then add all values.

This is what Table 1 looks like:

> **Account | Geo | Site | Date | Data1 | Data2** 
> Account 1  France  Paris   100   200 
> Account 1   France  Nantes  300   100 
> Account 3   Spain   Barcelona   500 300
> Account 4   Philippines Cebu    50  100

This is what's Table 2 looks like:

> **Account  | Geo   | Site |    Expense1    | Expense 2** 
> Account 1   France  Paris   1000    500 
> Account 3   Spain   Barcelona   400 600 
> Account 3   Spain   Madrid  800 100 
> Account 4   Philippines Cebu    500 200

The expected results are this:

> **Account  | Geo   | Data1 | Data2 | Expense1  | Expense2** 
> Account 1   France  400 300 1000    500 
> Account 3   Spain   500 300 1200    700 
> Account 4   Philippines 50  100 500 200

Is it possible in Big Query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It is possible in BigQuery or any other Databases. Just read about join.

Query will look like

```
select  t11.Account, t11.Geo , t11.sum_data1, t11.sum_data2, t12.sum_expense1, t12.sum_expense2
from
(   
    select t1.Account, t1.Geo , sum(t1.Data1) sum_data1, sum(t1.Data2) sum_data2
    from table1 t1  
    group by t1.Account, t1.Geo) t11
inner join (    
    select t2.Account, t2.Geo , sum(t2.Expense1) sum_expense1, sum(t2.Expense2) sum_expense2
    from table2 t2  
    group by t2.Account, t2.Geo) t12
on t11.Account = t12.Account 
and t11.Geo = t12.Geo
```

There can be many variant of joins based on your requirement:

1. **INNER** : If you are sure all account geo combination are present in both tables.
2. **FULL OUTER** : If you both table have entries of account, geo which are not present in other table.
3. **LEFT OUTER** : If you want table1 to be driving table and don't want to miss any record of that even account + geo doesn't exist in table2.
4. **RIGHT OUTER** : Same as above but driving table will be table2.

Comment: Looking at your answer, I think I know now why my query is not working. I did some changes, anyway thank you!

Comment: now that I'm validating the data, I've noticed that the result of the sum of Data1 and Data2 doubled. So for example, Account1 in France shows that Data1 has 800 instead of 400.

Comment: Ahhh, I got that. It is because of many-to-many relationship. I will make changes to my original answer.

Comment: Please check now.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you. Learned a lot from you as well.